# excel 2010 add months to 31 day month

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to add 6 months to a date but if the day is not available then move to first of next month.

Example 8/31/17 plus 6 months wants February 31 so March 1 is desired. Want to move forward not back to last day of month. Same for any month where day doesn't match.

Comment: Try `=EDATE(A1,6)`. Where `A1` is the your base date, and `6` is the number of months to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

`=IF(DAY(EDATE(B2,6))<DAY(B2),EDATE(B2,6)+1,EDATE(B2,6))`

`Edate(08/31/17,6)=02-28-18`
Edate will go backward to the end of the month that is why I am testing the day to be the same of the initial date and add 1 to move forward in case it is not the same(if less)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I have used edate many times just didn't think to tell it to add 1 if not the same. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: READING COMPREHENSION FAIL - I didn't see the request for roll forward... Will leave the answer and edit when I figure it out, or delete if someone beats me to it.**

You could average the number of days in the month and advance by that using something like:

`=A1+((365/12)*6)`

In action:

`Thursday, 31 August 2017 -> =A1+((365/12)*6) -> Thursday, 1 March 2018`

However, this can result in an off-by-one issue on other dates...

---

Old Answer:

I'm pretty sure (like 99%) that you're looking for the `EDATE` function.

You can use it like so:

`=EDATE(A1, 6)`

Where `A1` is the your base date, and `6` is the number of months to add.

`Thursday, 31 August 2017 -> =EDATE(A1, 6) -> Wednesday, 28 February 2018`

The function will output the serial number of the date, so you'll need to format the output cell as a Date to see the result.